# flask_babel flash doesn't update in GAE in production

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, flask-babel

I'm implementing i18n with flask_babel like below and it works in local server.
However it doesn't work in production after deploy.
It can show translated with "_('English')", however it does show {{ _('English')}} as is in HTML.
Is there any way to show an appropriate message in HTML?

[main.py]

```
from flask_babel import gettext as _

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def root():
    flash(_('English'), 'success')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

[index.html]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ _('English')}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on your logs? Also, could you share some screenshots to compare the expected vs what you are getting?

Comment: Thanks Luis for your kind advice!
I've checked my log and found that there is no log shown even I set print(), that means my root() is not working correctly.
After checking app.yaml, I've found that all html are uploaded static and that prevent dynamic language change. I removed unnecessary setting in app.yaml and it finally works as expected.
Thanks again for your help!